# Java Maps/Data Structures - How to have a Value look at previous Key's values and pull down anything that didn't change?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, hashtable

I'm using a Map in Java to solve a problem, but I'm not seeing how I can compare a certain key's values to a previous key's values and then drag on whatever is not being updated.

[image: Referenced Table]

In the table below, we see Loan Swaps involving 4 companies that are occurring (in this example) from 1/1/2020 to 1/30/2020.
All in all, the participation percentage needs to add up to 100 of all the companies no matter the swaps, like this:

- Before Swap Date: company 1 (10) + company 2 (60) + company 3 (10) +
  company 4 (20) = 100
- 1/15/2020 Swap Date: company 1 (10) + company
  2 (30) + company 3 (40) + company 4 (20) = 100
- 1/21/2020 Swap Date: company 1 (10) + company 2 (50) + company 3 (20) + company 4
  (20) = 100
- 1/30/2020 Swap Date: company 1 (0) + company 2 (50) +
  company 3 (20) + company 4 (30) = 100

That is the goal of my code. This is my current thought process, but I'm stuck on how to pull down the values from a previous key value pair if they are not being changed due to a swap -- in particular how to accomplish the parts in red. [image: thought process]

Any insight is greatly appreciated.